# Logistics project that implements several shipping APIs

Tags: python, object-oriented, api, polymorphism

I have a Python logistic project that implements several shipping APIs using class inheritance. Each of those classes must do three things:

- Fire requests to each endpoint with the proper parameters
- Serialize and map the original input in order to store it
- Finally, produce a document according to the specification of each company

I firstly thought it unmantainable to have all this things together in a single giantic file, despite dealing with so unrelated tasks such as sending HTTP requests and formatting a PDF file. Finally, I've came across this directory structure:

```
shipment/
  shipment.py - primitive Shipment class (for mapping data)
  printer.py - primitive Printer class (for producing documents)
  controller.py - primitives for sending requests, inherits Shipment and has Printer instance as member

providers/
  provider1/
    shipment.py - implements shipment.Shipment
    printer.py - implements shipment.Printer
    controller.py - implements shipment.Controller
  provider2/
    shipment.py
    printer.py
    controller.py
```

As you can see, each shipping provider class has been splitted into 3 separate files. `Printer` is inherited by `Controller`, and provides the "summary_to_pdf" method.

shipment/controller.py:

```py
import logging
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from datetime import datetime
from os import environ
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from lib.database import db, ReturnDocument
from lib.model import Shipment, IndividualShipment, Sale

def ProviderClass(mapping_name:str, shipment_class:type, printer_class:type, url:str, packets_limit:int=0, asynchronous:bool=False):
    def decorator(cls):
        cls.mapping_name = mapping_name
        cls.Shipment = shipment_class
        cls.Printer = printer_class
        cls.url = url
        cls.packets_limit = packets_limit
        cls.asynchronous = asynchronous
        class NewClass(cls, printer_class, ShipmentController):
            __name__ = cls.__name__
            pass

        return NewClass
    return decorator

def ProviderInit():
    def decorator(init):
        def new_init(self, **kwargs):
            self.profile = kwargs
            self.Printer.__init__(self, **kwargs)
            ShipmentController.__init__(self, **kwargs)
            init(self, **kwargs)

        return new_init
    return decorator

class ShipmentHealthException(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, message:str):
        self.message = message
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Shipment health check failed: {message}'

class ShipmentController:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.raw_posting_objects = []
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('shipment')

    def build_shipment(self, **kwargs):
        self.raw_posting_objects = kwargs['posting_objects']
        return self.Shipment(**{ **kwargs, **self.profile, 'sender': self.profile['business'] })

    def insert(self, shipment, stamp:str, local_id:str, foreign_id:str):
        payload = {
            'shipment_profile': self.profile['_id'],
            'created_at': datetime.now(),
            'stamp': stamp,
            'local_id': local_id,
            'foreign_id': foreign_id,
            'objects_count': len(shipment)
        }

        shipment_id = Shipment.insert(**payload).inserted_id
        for s in shipment:
            db['sales'].find_one_and_update({ '_id': s['_id'] }, { '$set': { 'shipment': shipment_id } })

        return shipment_id

    @classmethod
    def _get_id(cls):
        return db['shipments'].count_documents({})

    @classmethod
    def _get_individual_id(cls):
        _id = 100000 + db['sales'].count_documents({
            'local_individual_shipment_id': {
                '$ne': None
            }
        })
        return str(_id)

    @staticmethod
    def instantiate(provider_mapping, **kwargs):
        return provider_mapping[kwargs['provider']['controller']](**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def _raise_not_implemented(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError('Method not implemented for this provider ({})'.format(cls.__name__))

    @abstractmethod
    def check_health(self):
        '''Checks whether provider is operational or not
        Implemented in:
            - Correios
        '''
        self._raise_not_implemented()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_id(self):
        '''Client unique ID for shipment provider
        Implemented in:
            - Correios
            - Jadlog
        '''
        self._raise_not_implemented()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_labels(self, **kwargs):
        '''Requests provider for label (tracking code) numbers
        Implemented in:
            - Correios
        '''
        self._raise_not_implemented()

    @abstractmethod
    def append_verifier_digit(self, **kwargs):
        '''Appends verifier digits in label numbers
        Implemented in:
            - Correios
        '''
        self._raise_not_implemented()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_services(self, save_to_db=False, **kwargs):
        '''Asks provider for available shipment services
        Implemented in:
            - Correios
            - Jadlog
        '''
        self._raise_not_implemented()

    def request_already_sent_shipment(self, _list, local_shipment_id, service_id):
        unsent = [ sale for sale in _list if not sale.get('individual_shipment') ]
        for sale in unsent:
            self.request_individual_shipment(sale, sale['_id'])

        return local_shipment_id, self.build_shipment(posting_objects=_list)

    @abstractmethod
    def request_shipment(self, **kwargs):
        '''Sends PLP to be acquited by provider
        Implemented in:
            - Correios
        '''
        return self.request_already_sent_shipment(**kwargs)

    @abstractmethod
    def _request_individual_shipment(self, **kwargs):
        '''Requests a single object shipment (in case of asynchronous shipment)
        Implemented in:
            - Jadlog
        '''
        self._raise_not_implemented()

    def request_individual_shipment(self, item:dict, item_id, **kwargs):
        query = {
            '_id': ObjectId(item_id),
            'individual_shipment': None
        }

        sale = Sale.find_one(**query)
        if not sale:
            raise Exception('order already dispatched')

        foreign_id, code = self._request_individual_shipment(item, **kwargs)
        foreign_id = str(foreign_id)

        local_id = self._get_individual_id()

        individual_shipment = IndividualShipment.insert(local_id=local_id, foreign_id=foreign_id, code=code).inserted_id

        item = db['sales'].find_one_and_update({ '_id': sale['_id'] }, { '$set': { 'individual_shipment': individual_shipment } }, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
        return foreign_id, local_id, code

    @abstractmethod
    def request_updated_shipment(self, **kwargs):
        '''Retrieves previous sent PLP
        Implemented in:
            - Correios
        '''
        self._raise_not_implemented()
```

Feel free to make comments overall comments as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems reasonable to me, basing your implementation on generic objects that are specialized for specific uses.

What I might do differently is the overall architecture.  Is there a need for the functionality to be implemented as a single process?  Given the disparate requirements I think I would have structured it as a system of micro-services speaking together over a queuing system (e.g. RabbitMQ).  Each program then becomes a simple loop of read input, process the input, based on the process result send the result to the appropriate next processor. The last sub-step of choosing the next processor can be done in a switchboard processor which can additionally provide a view of how well the system is working.

A micro-service architecture will have code that is simplified but your deployment will become more complex since you have to successfully deploy all the micro-service processors to have the system "up". Bringing the system down will require that you first drain all the queues. However a controlled shutdown will require something similar in a unified program if you want to insure that all data read is processed before shutting down.